# Why do the results always turns out to be the same even if I change the parameter inside the function COUNT()?

Tags: sql, ms-access

The results of the three following code fragments turns out to be the same no matter what parameters are inside the parenthesis of function COUNT(), why?

```
SELECT Category.Category, Category.CategoryID, COUNT(Category) AS Popularity
FROM FavCategory INNER JOIN Category
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
HAVING COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID)>=2;

SELECT Category.Category, Category.CategoryID, COUNT(FavCategory.CategoryID) AS Popularity
FROM FavCategory INNER JOIN Category
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
HAVING COUNT(FavCategory.CategoryID)>=4;

SELECT Category.Category, Category.CategoryID, COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID) AS Popularity
FROM FavCategory INNER JOIN Category
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
HAVING COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID)>=2;

SELECT Category.Category, Category.CategoryID, COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID+Category.CategoryID) AS Popularity
FROM FavCategory INNER JOIN Category
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
HAVING COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID)>=2;
```

Here are the records on the Category and FavCategory table
[image]

Comment: What's the results of COUNT of CategoryID 1 and 3 on your first query?

Comment: 3 for CategoryID 3 and 2 for CategoryID 1

Answer (score 2):

You are asking about the why. They are all the same, as `COUNT` counts depending on if a field/expression is not null or null. If the value is not null, `COUNT` counts it; if null, it ignores it

You don't have any nulls on your table, hence all your three queries report the same value.  Try `COUNT('DRACULA')`, `COUNT(42)`, `COUNT(0)` or even `COUNT(-1)`, they will count **3 for CategoryID 3 and 2 for CategoryID 1**, they will work the same as your three queries.

And of course, you can also use `COUNT(*)` if you are using `INNER JOIN`, and it is [advisable](http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/debunking-myth-that-countdracula-is.html). If you are using `LEFT JOIN`, it's incorrect to use `COUNT(*)`, you must do this: `COUNT(secondTable.foreignKeyColumnHere)`; or if Access supports counting based on cardinality(like in Postgresql), just do this: `COUNT(secondTable.*)`

For a primer on counting and enlightenment regarding its proper use (plug alert), read my post about count at http://www.ienablemuch.com/2010/04/debunking-myth-that-countdracula-is.html

---

@JDein

Given this data:

```
create table Person
(
  PersonId int not null primary key, 
  Name varchar(100) not null, 
  Middlename varchar(100) null
);

insert into Person(PersonId,Name,MiddleName) values
(1,'John','Winston'),
(2,'Paul','James'),
(3,'George',NULL),
(4,'Ringo','Parkin');
```

All of these would return 4:

```
select count(PersonID) from Person;

select count(Name) from Person;

select count(*) from Person;

select count(1) from Person;

select count(0) from Person;

select count(2) from Person;

select count(-1) from Person;

select count(42) from Person;

select count('Dracula') from Person;
```

Except for the following, this returns 3:

```
select count(MiddleName) from Person;
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1b1e/8

Comment: I'm a novice. Could you please explain what COUNT('DRACULA'), COUNT(42), COUNT(0),COUNT(1) and COUNT(-1) mean.

Comment: @JDein That's a tongue-in-cheek way of saying that any parameter to COUNT, as long that the parameter it is not null, it is counted as 1 :-)

Comment: That's why all your queries on your question, returns the same COUNT

Answer (score 1):

My *guess* is that you're actually after distinct values for the column, in which case use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT (FavCategory.CategoryID))
```

(etc).

From the [SQL Server documentation for COUNT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) (you haven't specified which database you're using):

> COUNT(ALL expression) evaluates expression for each row in a group and returns the number of nonnull values.

(I believe ALL is the default, as opposed to DISTINCT.)

Given that none of the values are null in your tables, just using an expression is equivalent to `COUNT(*)` - i.e. it'll return the row count for the group. That's why every expression is giving the same result.

If you weren't after distinct results, please explain what you're trying to achieve, and we may be able to suggest an alternative. (Well, someone else may be able to - I suspect I won't, being a SQL beginner.)

Comment: Well, I'm using MS Access, which doesn't support the syntax you mentioned, say, COUNT(DINSTINCT parameter). What I want to know is the popularity of each film category.

Comment: @JDein: Well then I'd use `COUNT(*)` - you just want to know the number of rows in each group, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you want that the popularity could be seen more easily in the results, you should probably add an `ORDER BY` clause to sort the results by the COUNT column:

```
SELECT
  Category.Category,
  Category.CategoryID,
  COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID) AS Popularity
FROM FavCategory INNER JOIN Category
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
HAVING COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID)>=2
ORDER BY Popularity DESC;
```

Perhaps you would also like to include categories that are not among the favourite ones. In that case you would need to replace `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` and swap the sides of the join:

```
SELECT
  Category.Category,
  Category.CategoryID,
  COUNT(FavCategory.MemberID) AS Popularity
FROM Category LEFT JOIN FavCategory
ON FavCategory.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID
GROUP BY Category, Category.CategoryID
ORDER BY Popularity DESC;
```

Note also that in this case it is vital that you count values of one of the joined table's (`FavCategory`) columns (`MemberID` in the above example). If some categories do not have matches in `FavCategories`, `MemberID` would be NULL and, as a result, not counted by COUNT.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the row count for combination of  Category, Category.CategoryID. What these means is that DB will create all the unq combination of these 2 colums and then print the rows count for these each unq combination. If you have same cols in group clause and same where clause than your row count will not change. Having can effect on the row count but without data to look at its very difficult to tell if its having any effect